# Can media queries be used in Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

Can media queries be used in Outlook (all versions). I'm trying to style a `div` when at 640px, but Outlook does not seem to fire the styling.

Any ideas?

Comment: I highly doubt it.

Comment: Outlook doesn't readily support divs. Try a parent table, put the width on the <td>, and then use the media query to adjust the width of the <td>.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Outlook does not really have any solid support for media queries unfortunately and is often 'left out' when it comes to mobile responsive emails.

This [link here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/) should help in explaining email responsivity and gives you a good amount of detail.

Comment: Just brilliant, why do all customers use Outlook? It's like using a old Nokia when you have a iPhone :(

Comment: @regen Because a majority of PC are Windows ones and Office is extremly common maybe?

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that versions of Outlook that do not support media queries are not mobile anyhow. Mobile versions of Outlook (iOS and Android) of Outlook do support media queries.

Comment: Not entirely correct. There are web versions of Outlook that don't support media queries OR mso conditional code. Anyone with a browser on their phone can access Outlook.com for the web.

Comment: Do you know what those versions are? Wouldn't accessing Outlook.com in a browser leverage the browser's capabilities?

Comment: Unfortunately, accessing Outlook or any other client in the browser doesn't have any effect on preventing the changes made to the email's HTML and CSS by the client itself or what it will and won't render. Web clients are still apps that follow their own rules and restrictions. Gmail and Yahoo have recently changed their web clients in a way that getting an email to render correctly at all will be nearly impossible, and the app version of the client will be the only way to view email as it was intended to be displayed.