# outlook media@ problems outlook not responsive

Tags: html, css, outlook, ms-word

we are tryin to make modify an email for making it work in outlook and media@ don't seem to work. im out of idea,

this doesn't seem to work to

here the base model i took for outlook specification with css but it don't seems to work

```
<!--[if mso]>
    <style>
        .example-class {
            /* Outlook-specific CSS goes here. */
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

soo i tried simple test with changing the background color first with a nice looking red
but it doesn't seem to actually do something. i don't realy know what i can do

```
<!--[if mso]>

    <style>
        .table {
            background-color : red !important;
        }

        .body { 
            background-color : red !important;
        }


    </style>

<![endif]-->



  </head>

  <body
    class="clean-body"
    style="
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 auto ;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      color-scheme: light only;">
    <!--[if IE]><div class="ie-container"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if mso]><div class="mso-container"><![endif]-->
    <table
       background="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/612d92faee8b9d13af4cd235/61bdeff1d3a394e5d362a8d2_signaturebackground.png" width="600" height="auto"  
      style="
        max-width: 600px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-spacing: 0;
        mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
        mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        vertical-align: top;
        min-width: 320px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-image: url('https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/612d92faee8b9d13af4cd235/61bdeff1d3a394e5d362a8d2_signaturebackground.png'); width:600px; display: block;
        background-color : rgb(33, 34, 34);
        color-scheme: light only;
        width: 100%;
        color: #ffffff;
       font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
       top : -50px;
            
      "
      cellpadding="0"
      cellspacing="0"
           
    >
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="min-width: 180px; width: 210px; padding-bottom: 37px;">
            <table style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
             
                  <td
                    style="
                      padding-left: 42px;
                      padding-bottom: 1px;
                      min-width: 83px;
                      padding-top: 40px;
                      padding-right: 0px;
                    "
                  >
                    <table>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="min-width: 180px">
                            <div
                              style="
                                font-size: 15px;
                                font-weight: 800;
                                line-height: 1;
                                color:rgb(126, 122, 122);filter: brightness(100);
                                     
                    
                              "
                            >
                              Inès AZUELOS
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <div
                              style="
                                font-size: 13px;
                                font-weight: 600;
                                padding-top: 5px;
                                padding-left: 1px;
                                color: #3399ff;"
                            >
                              Direction - Assistante
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="
                          padding-top: 16px;
                          padding-left: 2px;
                          color:rgb(126, 122, 122);filter: brightness(100);
                          font-size: 13px;
                          font-weight: 600;"
                          >
                            EICIAM
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td
                    style="
                      padding-left: 41px;
                      padding-bottom: 2px;
                      padding-right: 0px;
                      padding-top: 15px;
                      min-width: 83px;
                    "
                  >
                    <table>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td alt="logo facebook" title="logofacebook" style="padding: 3px; width : 20px; height: 20px;">
                           <a href=""> <img src="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; display: block;border :0;"/> </a>
                          </td>
                          <td alt="logo linkedin" title="logolinkedin" style="padding: 3px; width: 20px; height: 20px;">
                           <a href=""> <img style="width: 20px; height: 20px; display: block; border :0;"/> </a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>


                  <!-- --------------------- -->
                  <td style="padding: 33px 0 0 0; width: 226px; margin-left: 5px ">
                    <table>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="border-left: 1px solid #ffffff67; padding: 7px 0 0 19px;">
                            <table
                              style="
                                font-size: 11px;
                                color: #212222;
                                letter-spacing: 0.7px;
                              "
                            >
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="min-width: 170px">
                                    <table>
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td alt="phone" title="phone" style="min-width: 19px; padding-top: 2px; width: 20px; height: 20px;"> 
                                           <img src="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; display: block; border : 0;" />
                                          </td>
                                          <td href=""style="color:rgb(126, 122, 122);filter: brightness(100%); padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 12px;"><a href=""> </a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td alt="mail" title="mail"  style="padding-top: 13px; width: 20px; height : 20px;">
                                            <img src="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; display: block; border : 0;"  />
                                          </td>
                                          <td style="padding-top: 16px; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 12px;">
                                           <a href="" style="color:rgb(126, 122, 122);filter: brightness(100);" > </a>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td alt="web" title="web" style="padding-top: 12px; width: 20px; height: 20px;">
                                             <img src="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; display: block; border: 0;" />
                                          </td>
                                          <td style="padding-top: 16px; padding-left: 10px;font-size: 12px;">
                                           <a href="" style="color:rgb(126, 122, 122);filter: brightness(100);"> eiciam.fr </a>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                     
                                          <tr>
                                          <td alt="print" title="print" style="padding-top: 15px;width: 20px; height: 20px; display:inline; border:0;">
                                          <img style="width: 20px; height: 20px; display: block; border :0;"  onerror="this.src=';"/> 
                                              </td>
                                               <td style="padding-top: 16px; padding-left: 10px">
                                           <a  style="color:rgb(126, 122, 122);filter: brightness(100); font-size: 9px" style="color: white;"> N'imprimez que si nécessaire </br> Pensez à l'environnement</a>
                                               </td>
                                          </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                  <td alt="" title="" style="min-width: 50px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border:0;">
                    <img src="" style="min-height: 50px; min-width: 50px; width: 100px; height: auto; display: block; border: 0;margin-top: 50px;"/>
                  </td>
                  <!-- ------------------------------ -->
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--[if mso]></div><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]></div><![endif]-->
  </body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can media queries be used in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027754/can-media-queries-be-used-in-outlook)

Comment: Nikita Skrebets, nope its doesn't work i kind of gived up

Answer (score 0):

The media element is not supported. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

The fact is that Outlook uses Word as an editor and rendering engine for message bodies.