# Responsive HTML text/images in Outlook365, gmail, etc

Tags: html, css, outlook, responsive

I have a PowerShell script that creates a single HTML file, `email.html`, with inline CSS and embedded base64 images.. then sends it daily to me (my website reports).

I want *all* (text/images) that are in the body of the email to resize automatically **based on the width of the email client viewable area**.  Admittedly, I have limited experience in HTML/CSS. What am I doing wrong in my example below?  Note: I truncated the base64 text in the example below so it doesn't take up too much space in my example.

Code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
    @media screen and (max-device-width:640px),
    screen and (max-width:640px) {
        .responsivetext {font-size: 2vw !important;width:auto;height:auto;vertical-align:middle}
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <td style="font-family: Arial;" class="responsivetext">I have tried everything.  Why wont this text resize when resizing Outlook 2016?</td>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAAIEAIAAADwyk6cAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABmJLR0T...." />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you can use table

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this situation too. It is very difficult to achieve success in all options.

> Outlook does not really have any solid support for media queries unfortunately and is often 'left out' when it comes to mobile responsive emails.
> [Can media queries be used in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027754/can-media-queries-be-used-in-outlook)

I suggest to you [here](https://unlayer.com/templates) you can create responsive html design and examine it.

Comment: Thanks. I know the desktop version of Outlook doesn't have very good support for media queries.  I was still hoping there was a way to at least get something working with limited support.

Comment: @MKANET What about content ? is it dynamic or static ? I mean , if content is like reset password or confirmation code than it can be easy. If content is complex as newspaper. you have to devote a lot of time. you can see html and css standards on the site which i mentioned. You can use some speacial breakpoints tag.  As far as I remember flex property doesnt support. you can start the tests using the tables. You can give the width as a percentage for th and td tags.

Comment: it's a daily report on which IP's visited my website based on nginx.log.  The output is always the same format.   If there's any way to do this, I'd like to know in a working html example.

Comment: format is not complex. I was really hoping someone would be kind enough to give me a working example based on the example html in my question.  I can figure out the rest.  I'd really appreciate it if you could post a working example using the example I posted.

Comment: @MKANET: the following is intended to be helpful advice. Your questions seem _always_ to be seeking examples. That's OK up to a point, but I am concerned that you are using Stack Overflow as a way to obtain free work, rather than to obtain useful steering and pointers that a self-actualised and experimenting engineer would be asking for.

Comment: I say that not to offend you, but in the hope that this meta-advice is useful for all of your future questions. I note that in nearly all of your questions, they are phrased in a way that makes requests of what other people can do for you. I would suggest that you write your questions in terms of what you can do for you: "How can I foo the bar" and "What is the most effective way of bopping the widget" are excellent ways of indicating to your audience that **you intend to do most of the work on your problem**.

Comment: Moreover, if you can get into that habit, not only is that a good signal to your readers, who will regard you as worth helping, but you'll be persuading yourself that **you can do it**. I think this is helpful in leading towards a mindset of being a (more) self-actualised engineer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working in HTML email development for a few years now and Outlook is the biggest client that makes this job so difficult.

This is a very useful resource for understanding what will and won't work on the various email clients available >> https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-selector-id/

There are a few things you'll need to know about email clients and HTML emails:

1. Most email clients have overriding CSS that will change the way your HTML displays. Using CSS style resets in the <head> of your document will help avoid this from happening.
2. It matters a lot which styles are used on which HTML elements (e.g. you can add padding to a <td> tag, but you can't add padding to a <p> tag)
3. The size of your actual screen is what will determine how your HTML displays inside Outlook, NOT the Outlook window size. You can resize the client window as much as you want, but it will still use the size of the actual display screen to determine how to display the HTML.
4. I'm not sure if there was more code that was left off, but you can't use a <td> all by itself. It has to be wrapped in <table> and <tr>

You can try the code below. It probably won't resize with the window, but if you open it on a mobile device the email will be resized to match the screen size.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
  /* HTML Email CSS Resets and Body Font */
  body, .body {
      text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important; font-size: 16px; font-size: medium;
      font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;
  }
  .resizer, * { width: 100%; font-size:1em; }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .resizer, * { font-size:2vw; }
  }

</style>

</head>

<body class="body">
  <table class="resizer">
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle" height="auto" width="auto">
        <p>I have tried everything.  Why wont this text resize when resizing Outlook 2016?</p>
        <br>
        <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/921/921594.png" style="width:10vw;" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```